# R getMinCircle failing - how to fix (or alternatives to find minimum circle encompassing data)

Tags: r

I am using [getMinCircle](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/shotGroups/versions/0.7.5.1/topics/getMinCircle) to find the minimum circle that encompasses my data - it works exactly as expected some of the time, but not others.

Is there a reason why this is failing (and something I can do about it), or is there an alternative to this function?

The data is https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r4OgvHgUn66PNl5aFfMkmSXnyeO_dJIB/view?usp=sharing

```
library(shotGroups)

df <- read.csv("test.csv")
mc <- getMinCircle(df)

xLims <- mc$ctr[1] + c(-mc$rad, mc$rad)
yLims <- mc$ctr[2] + c(-mc$rad, mc$rad)
plot(point.y ~ point.x, data=df,
     pch=16, asp=1, xlim=xLims, ylim=yLims)
drawCircle(mc, fg='blue')
```

Comment: I haven't dug through this yet, but I strongly suspect that the problem is that there are sets of collinear points in your data set, which is confusing the algorithm.

Comment: Thanks - that could certainly be the case.  All of my datasets are like this, but if it's not picking up everything that would explain why it works some times but not others.  Might have to look into doing it myself.

Comment: I don't know how familiar you are with debugging R code.  The way I started to work my way through was to do `debug(shotGroups:::getMinCircle.default)` (which contains the actual algorithm, after some pre-preprocessing has been done to convert the data to a two-column matrix), then plot things step by step to see what was happening. It might (?) be possible to hack what's there to remove collinear points? (At the very least one could try hand-deleting the collinear points for one example and seeing if that resolved the problem ...)

Comment: It would be very clunky but I *think* one could work through the convex-hull points iteratively, testing if {n+1} was between {n, n+2}, and removing it if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I'll work through this and report back if I manage to get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in package `shotGroups`. `getMinCircle()` tacitly assumed that the output from `chull()` would contain no collinear points without checking for this. The author was made aware of the issue you raised, and tried to fix it in version 0.8 by removing collinear points from the convex hull - as suggested in the comment by Ben. For the sample data in your post, it now works.

```
library(curl)
id   <- "1r4OgvHgUn66PNl5aFfMkmSXnyeO_dJIB"
sURL <- sprintf("https://docs.google.com/uc?id=%s&export=download", id)
con  <- curl(sURL)
df   <- read.csv(con)

library(shotGroups)
mc    <- getMinCircle(df)
xLims <- mc$ctr[1] + c(-mc$rad, mc$rad)
yLims <- mc$ctr[2] + c(-mc$rad, mc$rad)
plot(point.y ~ point.x, data=df,
     pch=16, asp=1, xlim=xLims, ylim=yLims)
drawCircle(mc, fg='blue')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @caracal - my own attempts to achieve this were far less successful.